Can you use an external USB drive for the Xbox 360 operating system?
So I lost my Xbox 360 hard drive and knowing how costly the Xbox 360 hard drives are, I want to use my 128GB USB to become a default system hard drive. Can I do this? Is it possible to use an external USB drive as the main Xbox 360 system drive?
